# Program does not react for Process.Exited

Tags: c#, wpf, vbscript

I'm trying to run some script (VBScript as an example) in WPF/C# application and make it close itself after script running finished.

```
        string scriptName = "test.vbs";
        int abc = 2;
        string name = "Script";

        ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
        ps.FileName = "cscript.exe";
        ps.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\"", scriptName, abc, name);

        Process p = new Process();            
        p.StartInfo = ps;
        p.Exited += this.End;
        p.Start();
        p.Close();
```

How can I do this? Event "Exited" just doesn't happen.

Actually absence of p.EnableRaisingEvents = true was a problem. Correct code is:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.StartInfo = ps;
        p.Exited += this.End;
        p.Start();
```

Comment: What is your `End` function?

Comment: p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

Comment: You are calling `p.Close()`, which releases all of the resources related to the `Process` object, including those used to monitor the process state and raise the `Exited` event. So, just don't call `Close()` (at least, not until you're done with the object!). And, set `EnableRaisingEvents`.

Comment: End is just extension method used for debug. It just shows message box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463398/exited-event-of-process-is-not-rised

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457252/issue-with-process-exited

Answer (score 2):

You close the process before waiting until it has finished.

[`p.WaitForExit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to be the better way of waiting for the process to finish in this case (as long as you don't want to do anything else in parallel while the process is running).

```
using (Process p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo = ps;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    // Do whatever you want to do after the process has finished
}
```